# Hibernate Throws a SQLException When Distinctly Selecting only Two of Three Mapped Columns

Tags: sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a table, CityComplete, with columns "USPSCITY", "STATE" and "ZIPCODE"

I have an existing SQLQuery that distinctly selects USPSCITY and STATE based on a fuzzy search.  However, when I call list() I get an exception:

```
19. ResultSet.getString(ZIPCODE)
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'ZIPCODE' not found.
```

The SQLQuery's entity is set to the CityComplete object.

Is there any way to have Hibernate *not* try and get ZIPCODE, or have it be part of the result set in some way?

What's the best way to resolve this, other than using Criteria, setting a virtual column with null data, or just getting a full result set and handling distinction on the code side?

Comment: show your entity, and the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform a regular Hibernate query (HQL or Criteria), Hibernate will try to map the resultset based on the properties of the entities which you specified in the mapping. If you are not bringing the "promised" data from the database, you'll need to handle the mapping by yourself, using a `ResultTransformer`. In this case, you'd still use your `CityComplete`, but they will be without a `ZIPCODE`. Unfortunately, there's not much documentation about how to use a `ResultTransformer`, but you can take a look at the Hibernate's JavaDoc and see if there's one that you could use. If not, you'd need to implement your own:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html